# How to remove group fieldname from Listview WebPart

Tags: 2010, list-view, xslt

When using a ListView WebPart on a custom list and enable grouping for a view, the name of the group is always displayed as the first entry
[image: List view screenshot]

I tried to find a way to get rid of the “Category:” label and found some different hints in the internet, but none really worked.

- [List View - Group By - without field name](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f514fa73-5b35-402d-b43a-19f1580ca9bc/list-view-group-by-without-field-name)

-> no entry with  “xsl:value-of select="$fieldtitle” found in Designer

- [SharePoint: Removing Group Headings from a View’s Group By](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.de/2009/06/sharepoint-removing-group-headings-from.html)

-> in my Custom View named “GroupedView.aspx” there was no “GroupByField” value (even search in notepad after copying the whole xslt from the designer found nothing)

The only thing that worked was a [JS script I found on the blogspot from Amit Phule from 2011](http://amitphule.blogspot.com/2011/10/hiding-group-headers-from-sharepoint.html)

Is there really no other way then using an client side script to remove those entries afterwards?

EDIT: Sorry Guys, as my first Screenshot was quite unhelpful, I modified the list a bit.

I want to get rid of the groupname "Category" over every Group.

[image: Grouped listview with "groupname : value"]

Comment: Not to be that guy, but having Categories named "Category 1" and so on, instead of just "1" seems quite redundant

Comment: Even further, if you are grouping by category, why is it even a column in the display? It's not necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I just made some Screenshots of a new List, because I didn't want to bother you with entries from a german list ;) My Category name are "Objekt-Info", "Fachpresse",... But still the name of the Categoryfield is added to the display.

Comment: Seems like the JS solution is the only way, sad but true.

Comment: Open the page in sp designer and change the text colour to white. Vwala its gone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure you have resolved your problem. Yesterday I was looking for a solution as you asked.  But for now, my problem is resolved by using jQuery.

Here is the result of my screen short:

[image]

I don't have any server client permission. My solution is write jQuery in CEWP.

Here is the code which i made:

[image]

Please note: 'Stage' is the field name which we need to replace. 'M1' and 'Start' is the name which we want to present. 
in the screen short, the line of "var i=0" should be "var i=1"

Comment: Can you please add more details about what code you used and how?

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don`t want to replace the headers, I wanted to delete them.
 Another Issue with your idea is, that I have to modify the script each time a new category is added. 
Until now I used the JS snippet from Amit Phule linked in my question and it works as expected. The reason I posted the question above is, that I can't believe that there is no OOB way to do this :(

Comment: your are right, my idea is not too much flexible. but it's resolved my problem currently:)    I going to take a test of Amit Phule solution.